# metric tensor components for a space homeomorphic to $S^{n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I'm interested in metric tensors on compact spaces, as constructed from group properties of those spaces.

For a simple example, consider some closed 1-dimensional space that is homeomorphic to a circle. Considering for a moment this space as being embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we can write the equation of our 1-surface in standard Cartesian coordinates as:

$$x^{2}+y^{2}=f^{2}(x,y)$$

Knowing that we plan on parameterizing our equation in terms of 1 coordinate (let's choose the standard polar coordinate $\phi)$, we have a condition for periodicity:

$x(\phi+2\pi)=x(\phi)$

$f(x(\phi),y(\phi))=f(\phi)$ can be seen as being the distance of our surface from the origin at angle $\phi$.

Supposing $f(\phi)$ is a well behaved function (in the sense of being Fourier series expandable), and knowing that, by design: $f(\phi)\in L^{2}(S^{1})$, we can expand our function as:

$$f(\phi)=a_{0}+\sum_{1}^{\infty}\{a_{n}\cos(n\phi)+b_{n}\sin(n\phi)\}$$

Being interested in the metric “tensor” (just a scalar here) and accompanying quadratic form, we get:

$$ds^{2}=\left\{ f^{2}(\phi)+\frac{\partial f(\phi)}{\partial\phi}\frac{\partial f(\phi)}{\partial\phi}\right\} d\phi^{2}$$

So is the metric tensor/scalar the bracketed term?

Please note, I'm actually interested in more general compact spaces, say for example a space homeomorphic to the two-sphere:

$$x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=f^{2}(x,y,z)$$

I'm thinking the metric tensor is in general some sort of jacobian applied to f???

I'm interested in the general way one would find the components of their metric tensor for a space homeomorphic to $S^{n}$.

BONUS:  ultimately I want to apply the Peter-Weyl theorem to these compact spaces (topologies) and express the metric in terms of matrix coefficients of irreducible representations of a group (where we would use U(1) for the 1-d example above for instance).